# Where can I find out the Microsoft Edge browser version I have?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have the Microsoft Edge browser, where can I find the browser version number?

Usually in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, I can find in the **Help -> About**. In Edge, I can't see any direct option like that.

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Edge, there is no option like Help -> About, the version number is under the Settings option.

The following steps helped to find the browser version number:

1. Click the ellipses icon in the right top corner of the browser.

> [image: ellipses icon]

2. In the option window, scroll to bottom to see the **Settings** option.

> [image: Settings]

3. In the Settings window, scroll to bottom, ther you can see the **About this app**

> [image: About this app]

4. There you can find the Microsoft Edge browser version.